# Comment after "examples table" produces an error: "examples column count mismatch" - Karate maven 1.2.0.RC4

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate maven 1.2.0.RC4 and everything right with my features. Today I decided to update to 1.2.0.RC5 but then a new error appears.
There is something new that can affect to this in this version?

The feature is a scenario outline with "Examples" table. The problem is related with the comment at the end of the row because if I delete the comment there is no error.

**The line 43 where the error happens:**

[image]

**The error message:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the result of this bug-fix: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1923

You are welcome to debate this in the issue comments. My stand is that trailing comments like you had were never intended to be supported and I don't think it is valid Gherkin also.

You are welcome to contribute code to "fix" things :)